# parse error in haskell file with unicode symbol

Tags: haskell, unicode

It's probably very stupid, but I get a

parse error on input ‘⊥’

when I process this file

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --install-ghc --resolver lts-5.13 runghc --package http-conduit
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, RankNTypes, MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, UnicodeSyntax, PartialTypeSignatures #-}
module MainImplicitConfiguration where

a = ⊥
```

Is there a reason why that should be a parse error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
a = (⊥)
```

(along with `LANGUAGE UnicodeSyntax`)

Comment: Maybe ⊥ is being treated as an infix symbol, like + , rather than a letter?

Comment: Not sure exactly what the rules are. I got a hint from [this old Haskell Cafe message](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2008-January/037723.html). Seems like you can use ⊥ as a name as long as you use parens, e.g. `(⊥) = 'z'`

Comment: The Unicode category for this codepoint is probably "symbol", which is why Haskell regards it as a punctuation mark (like "+", which is Unicode "PLUS SIGN" category Sm, "Symbol, Math"). Every Unicode character has various properties such as category, case, etc.